# SQLITE : near " of " syntax error(code 1); While compiling INSERT INTO MyTable

Tags: c#

i trying to add my record into my table but it appear this syntax error.

Here is my code.
Code image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/un0jW.png

```
public void CreateDatabase(string sqldb_name)
        {
            try
            {
                sqldb_message = "";
                string sqldb_location = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                string sqldb_path = Path.Combine(sqldb_location, sqldb_name);
                bool sqldb_exists = File.Exists(sqldb_path);
                if (!sqldb_exists)
                {
                    sqldb = SQLiteDatabase.OpenOrCreateDatabase(sqldb_path, null);
                    sqldb_query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (_PhoneNumber INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name VARCHAR, Password VARCHAR, DateOfBirth VARCHAR);";
                    sqldb.ExecSQL(sqldb_query);
                    sqldb_message = "Database: " + sqldb_name + " created";
                }
                else
                {
                    sqldb = SQLiteDatabase.OpenDatabase(sqldb_path, null, DatabaseOpenFlags.OpenReadwrite);
                    sqldb_message = "Database: " + sqldb_name + " opened";
                }
                sqldb_available = true;
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                sqldb_message = ex.Message;
            }
        }
        //Adds a new record with the given parameters
        public void AddRecord(string PhoneNumber, string Pwd, string Name, string DOB)
        {
            try
            {
                sqldb_query = "INSERT INTO MyTable (PhoneNumber, Password, Name, Date Of Birth) VALUES ('" + PhoneNumber + "','" + Pwd + "'," + Name + "," + DOB + ");";
                sqldb.ExecSQL(sqldb_query);
                sqldb_message = "Record saved";
            }

            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                sqldb_message = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Remove *spaces*: `DateOfBirth` instead of `Date Of Birth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your column name does not much the one specified in insert. Use:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (_PhoneNumber, Password, Name, DateOfBirth) VALUES ...
```

Also USE PARAMETERS